# Is subclass: an ordinary method in Squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

It seems that creating a new subclass in Squeak is done by sending a message to the super class:

```
Object subclass: #Boolean
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Kernel-Objects'
```

Where can I look at the implementation of this method? I can't find it in `Object`'s nor `ProtoObject`'s class methods list.

Comment: Try looking in Behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is an ordinary message. The implementation is in the class called `Class`. You can find its implementation by selecting the message name in any class definition (like the one you posted in the question) and invoke the "implementors of it" action (Cmd-m, or in the pop up menu if you hold shift while clicking).

You will find that it delegates to ClassBuilder, where you can see how new classes come into existence.

Note that you send the message *to the class* Object, not to an instance of Object. That's why you did not find a method in `Object` or `ProtoObject`. You would rather have to look up the method in `Object class`, which is the metaclass of Object, and it inherits from `Class`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that `ClassBuilder` is created using the same message. So what came first, the chicken or the egg? 

Comment: @mstram The name of the method is actually `subclass:instanceVariableNames:classVariableNames:poolDictionaries:category:` (the whole selector you see when you look at a class definition).

Comment: @mstram There is no method that is simply called `subclass:` (at least not in the base system), there is only the longer one (and a few more variants of it, but these are distinct methods). In the code that you posted above, the whole name of the method with all the keywords is present, so I don't quite understand what you mean with "it jumps to the longer version". It just sends the message with the long name, it doesn't send `subclass:` without the rest of the name. Can you explain in more detail how you interact with the code? Maybe that will explain how you got your impression.

Comment: Or maybe there is a misunderstanding about the language: in the code snippet `myObject foo: 42 bar: 13` the message `foo:bar:` is sent to the object `myObject` with the arguments 42 and 13. There is no message `foo:` involved here. All the keywords belong together to form the method name, so to speak. It is just the same with that long-winded subclassing message.

Comment: I get it now.  I was mis-reading the "subclass:"  / " instanceVariableNames:'' ... as being *separate* methods, when in fact (obviously) they are all part of the same method clause (very beginner level Smalltalk here).

Comment: On another note, why am I getting a  "syntaxx error" ; {"Variable or expression or right brace expected ->"subclass: instanceVariableNames:  classVariableNames: poolDictionaries: category}

When I try to plug subclass: instanceVariableNames:  classVariableNames: poolDictionaries: category:  

into the "Method Finder / Selector Browser

Comment: Please try without the spaces after the colons.

Comment: As to the why, I don't know off the top of my head, but you could ask that on the [squeak-dev mailing list](https://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman3/lists/squeak-dev.lists.squeakfoundation.org/).